# How can I make a "read-only variable"?

Tags: shell, posix, sh

In Bash, you can create a [read-only variable](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/declare)

```
declare -r somevar='bla'
```

I tried to find something similar in POSIX `sh`, but the only thing that comes close is this phrase in the [`set` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/set.html):

> [...] read-only variables cannot be reset.

How can I create such a read-only variable?

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_23

Comment: Hmmm. My Google-fu failed me today.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make use of [`readonly`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/readonly.html):

```
$ var="hello"
$ readonly var
$ echo $var
hello
$ var="bye"
sh: var: readonly variable
```

Comment: I found [this as well](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh#declare_or_typeset), but can't locate it in the POSIX spec. Therefore I believe it to be an extension as well. I can see though it is [not present in certain shells](http://hyperpolyglot.org/unix-shells#variables).

Comment: OK, @jlliagre pointed me to the [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/readonly.html), which google apparently failed to accomplish. Where do I file bug reports for google search? :-p

Comment: Haha a workaround is having a coffee :) Based on that link, it is present in the spec. Does it suffice or is it still an extension? It is not clear to me.

Comment: It's not marked as an extension of any kind, so I guess it's fine :-). I edited in the Opengroup link if you don't mind :-)

Comment: It's not an extension, but it's one of the special builtin utilities that is documented in section 2.14 of the shell specification, rather than section 4.

Comment: @rubenvb In the link you give, `readonly` is missing from `fish` and `tcsh`; neither is POSIX-compatible.

Comment: @chepner, ah, I assumed that would be at least a common base. Foolish me :-) Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Yeah, just FYI, `tcsh` (like its predecessor `csh`) takes a different, more C-like approach to a shell language than the Bourne shell (which POSIX is ultimately based on). `fish` is more recent and also just eschewed POSIX compatibility in order to be more user-friendly.